# How to deserialize XML using RestSharp without a root node?

Tags: xml, serialization, restsharp

We have an XML response that looks like this:

```
<userresult>
   <username>
     Bill
   </username>
   <description>
     Man
   </description>
<userresult>
<userresult>
   ...
</userresult
<userresult>
   ...
</userresult
```

We are trying to deserialize this using:

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer deserial = new XmlDeserializer();
userresult userresult = deserial.Deserialize<userresult>(response);
```

Ideally, we'd like to deserialize the XML without a root node, but it appears the Deserializer method requires one.

What is our best approach to solving this? Is there a way around requiring a root node, if not, how can we add one?

We have created classes for each of the fields, such as:

```
    public class userresult
    {
        public List<username> userName { get; set; }
        public List<description> description { get; set; }
    }


    public class username
    {
        public string userName { get; set; }
    }
    public class description
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

The XML is coming to me from a provider and I cannot change the response.

Comment: root node is required. Without root node it is not valid xml. For not valid xml you need parse it by yourself and serialize every `userresult` separatly. You can wrap your response with some "dummy" node and deserialize it `var validXml = $"<root>{response}</root>"`.

Comment: @Fabio when trying this, it cannot convert a "string" type to "RestSharp.IRestResponse"

Comment: You can try update `IRestResponse.Content` -> `response.Content = $"<root>{response.Content}</root>"` if not the you can always use .Net `XmlSerializer` for deserializing "wrapped" xml. Remember using `response.Content` to get raw data of response

Comment: Ok, I've got this to compile and run. But I don't think is the right solutoin, because the output is now `<root>RestSharp.RestResponse</root>`, so they are not in the same level.

Comment: You need wrap `response.Content`